# How to use applescript to save a single Excel sheet as a PDF

Tags: excel, applescript, pdf-generation

I am using the following code:

```
set PDFName to --desired path and name of PDF file to save
set excelName to --desired path and name of Excel file to open

tell application "/Applications/Microsoft Excel.app"
    set isRun to running
    set wkbk1 to open workbook workbook file name excelName

    --Problem
    save (sheet "Invoice" of wkbk1) in PDFName as PDF file format
    --/Problem

    close wkbk1 saving no
    if not isRun then quit
end tell
```

I end up with the ENTIRE workbook converted to a 60-page-long-PDF, rather than only a single sheet!  Am I doing something wrong?  How can I fix this?

Comment: I think your answer is in Stackoverflow link : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37394771/applescript-excel-2016-save-as-pdf)

Comment: I actually used that post to write this coding.  The issue I'm having is different than the one he is having I think...

Comment: I tested it myself and despite the "save active sheet", it saves all the sheets in Excel 2011. It seems to be Excel bug ! Then I suggest to delete, before saving, all sheets you don't want to convert... then only the sheet you want will be converted. ... and close the workbook without saving.

Comment: Yes I have actually tried that..  The problem is that a lot of data on this sheet is pulled from the other sheets… So as soon as I delete the other sheets this data goes with it and I have nothing useable to convert to PDF...

Answer (score 0):

I tried to copy / paste values only in new sheet, but I failed. The paste special does...nothing.

So instead, I extracted the sheet of the first main document and copy it into a new temp document, then I am saving the temp document as PDF and close both new temp document and main document.

It works with script bellow:

```
set PDFPath to "Users:imac27:Desktop:Test22.PDF" -- destination of the PDF

tell application "Microsoft Excel"
activate
set SourceDoc to front document
set NameWB to name of front document -- get name of the document (for close)
tell SourceDoc to set SourceSheet to active sheet -- get sheet to be extracted
set newDoc to make new workbook -- create new workbook
tell newDoc
    set FirstSheet to first sheet of newDoc
    copy worksheet SourceSheet after FirstSheet -- copy sheet to be extracted in new doc
end tell
set display alerts to false -- to avoid warning "are you sure...?)
delete FirstSheet -- delete defautl sheet of new doc to keep only the copied sheet
save active sheet in PDFPath as PDF file format -- save temp workbook as PDf
close active workbook saving no -- close temp workbook
close workbook NameWB saving no -- close main document
end tell
```