# How to convert excel sheet to pdf automatically using applescript?

Tags: excel, macos, applescript

I am new to Mac and don't know anything about Applescript. I tried some previously discussed reference [Applescript Excel 2016 save as PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37394771/applescript-excel-2016-save-as-pdf) but I am not about some of the keywords/syntax such as documentPath, PDFPath, POSIX path of documentPath etc.
My filepath is "Macintosh HD:Users:sa:documents:folder_1" and my excel file name is dataworld.xls. I want to convert the first sheet of my workbook to pdf and pdf should be generated in the same place as filepath.
Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution, select the sheet and run the script:

```
set destinationFolder to (path to documents folder as text) & "folder_1:"
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    save as active sheet filename (destinationFolder & "dataworld.pdf") file format PDF file format
end tell
```

Comment: so in place of "folder_1:" should I put the path as "Macintosh HD:Users:sa:documents:folder_1" or also put the excel file name along with the path?

Comment: `(path to documents folder as text) & "folder_1:"` represents a relative path which is the same as  `"Macintosh HD:Users:sa:documents:folder_1"`

Comment: set destinationFolder to "Macintosh HD:Users:sa:documents:folder_1", I can omit the (path to documents folder as text) & "folder_1:" right?

Comment: It's highly recommended to use always relative paths to make the script portable.

Comment: Okay, understood. Thank you

Comment: Another question is where do I put "dataworld.xls" in the code and where do I specify sheet name?

Comment: My script assumes that the workbook is open. Instead of `active sheet` you can also specify `sheet "sheetName"`